# how to change the width and height of svg canvas by changing values by user at webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm using svg in my website. the size of svg canvas is in cm and i want to change the width and height of canvas by changing values at webpage. here's the code that i tried but did't worked..
the sniplet is not working due to jquery files, but you will get the idea by looking at the code

```js
var width = "21cm";
var height = "29.7cm";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sizeButton").click(function() {
    alert(width + " " + height);
    $("#sizes").toggle();
  });

  $(".size").click(function() {
    var size = $(this).text();

    if (size == "A4") {
      width = "21cm";
      height = "29.7cm";
    } else if (size == "Standard Newspaper") {
      width = "50cm";
      height = "50cm";
      var draw = SVG("mainSection").size(width, height);
    }
  });

  var draw = SVG("mainSection").size(width, height).style("border", "1px solid black");

  var rectangle = draw.rect('100%', '100%').style("fill", "none").style();
});
```

```html
<div id="sizeButton">Select Size</div>

<div id="sizes" style="display:none;">
  <div class="size">A4</div>
  <div class="size">Standard Newspaper</div>
</div>

<div id="mainSection">
</div>
```

Comment: 1) When adding a snippet there is a button named "tidy", it's wonderful, please use it! 2) Please check your snippet actually works before posting a question!

Comment: actually im new in stackoverflow, so don't know much about snippet. the only reason i added snippet was to add my code just to "show" what i tried, anyone can understand this simple code without running snippet. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Ok, you haven't said what errors you get? You really need to get a working snippet for us to test with you - without knowing the errors it's impossible to answer. `anyone can understand this simple code without running snippet` is not a good argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to know how to change the SVG size from the HTML?

In this example I have simply given two input boxes an id and a button a function to update the SVG canvas. If the fields are not numbers it will return an alert stating so.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("svg")
var update = function() {
  var w = document.getElementById('input1').value
  var h = document.getElementById('input2').value
  if (isNaN(w) || isNaN(h)) {
    alert("not a number")
  } else {
    svg.setAttribute("width", w)
    svg.setAttribute("height", h)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  x
  <input type="text" id="input1"></input>
  y
  <input type="text" id="input2"></input>
  <input type="submit" onclick="update()"></input>
  </br>
  </br>
  <svg id="svg">
        
  <path 
  d="M 0,0 1000,0 1000,1000 0,1000 z"
  fill="purple">
        </path>
   
</svg>


</div>
```